# ActivityManager keeps logging message "Launch Activity, postpone broadcast intents" for Android Widget with buttons

Tags: java, android, widget, broadcast, android-intent

I've got a homescreen widget that I've developed. It works, it just seems unresponsive. The only clue I've got as to why it's unresponsive at this point is that it prints the following in LogCat every time I click one of the two buttons:

ActivityManager   | Launch activity, postpone broadcast intents

I've done my google diligence, but haven't come up with a solution at this point. I have a lurking feeling that my activity is being killed as soon as it advances the data on the widget, and it has to be re-instantiated again before it can answer the intent. I am NOT calling the long-running background service every time, I'm just parsing the next String in a String[] and updating the RemoteViews with its data.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Is there something I should be doing differently?

Am I lost in the wasteland of android widgets?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you're doing wrong without seeing some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I was using BroadcastIntents when I should have been using ServiceIntents. Rewriting it to use a Service and ServiceIntents instead of BroadcastIntents and  Broadcast receiver was what it took to get it to respond reasonably.